# Amd intergrated Graphics drivers for ubuntu

Tags: drivers, graphics, ati, mame

I'm Building a mame (multiple arcade machine emulator) that runs anything from nes to gamecube and it's super budget, i figured the best way to save money is trying out lunix and maybe one day buying a copy of windows 7 if it would be optimal however i'm enjoying ubuntu as a project but would never run it on my personal machine.

on the arcade machine I'm running the amd samperon 3850 1.3ghz quad core, a asus AM1I-A 4gb of ram and on intergrated graphics because pciexpress 4X graphics cards are  expensive for how horrible they are

i'm running project 64 through playonlinux. i played my favorite n64 game (paper mario) and it functions fine other than any time i go to a different room/ area presumably due to a lack of drivers can some one point me in the right direction for drivers for ubuntu 14.04 drivers for an amd processor?
new to this so please dont sick the dogs on me
-Ubam

Answer (score 1):

Search for `Additonal Drivers` using Unity Dash (~ Start Menu). If there are any drivers available for your video card, they will show up here. I recommend `fglrx` over `fglrx-updates`, since the latter tends to have bugs.

Comment: i dont have a video card

Comment: You have to have some sort of graphics, and I use "video card" as a catchall term for video cards, video processors, etc.

Comment: i installed both fglrx and fglrx updates and it's doing the same thing. is it possible my cpu isn't capable of running pj64 on it's own?

Comment: It's possible, but it's more likely a problem with the emulator.